# Can't get a video playing with jQuery play()

Tags: jquery

I'd like jQuery to play my iframe video when a button is hit

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#play').click(function() {   //#play is the id of the button
        $('#video').get(0).play();  //video id
    });
});
```

I tried substituting the video id with

> $('iframe')

to no avail.

Comment: `$('#video').play();`  ???

Comment: Drop the `.get(0)` - that's not what `.get` does. You just need `$('#video').play();` If you are having problems selecting the button and video in the first place because they're in iframes, well, then you need to post much more HTML.

Comment: tried it both ways, not working

Comment: ^^ That's false, play() is a function of the DOM element, not the jQuery collection that $("#video") returns, thus the .get(0) is needed to actually refer to the DOM video element. Post your HTML (both the file with the iframe and the file in the iframe itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above suggestions worked. Instead, what did was:

```
     $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#play').click(function () {
        $('#video video')[0].play();  //looking for the video element in the parent
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the videos element is in an iframe

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#video').get(0).play();
```